# kendogrid not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

this is my kendo grid code . I see the data in the column but only this . I can't  sort data or filter. "Create" is my action and Profit is controller.What am i missing

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)    
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(model=> model.IdCategory.Name).Groupable(false);
            columns.Bound(model=> model.Value);
            columns.Bound(model => model.Description);
            columns.Bound(model => model.DateInput);
        })
        .Groupable()
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable()
        .Filterable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Create", "Profit"))
        )
        )
```

Comment: Share the controller, share the layout page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for any JavaScript errors in your browser developer tools. There is a list of common JavaScript errors: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/troubleshooting#javascript-error-that-kendo-widgets-are-unavailable-or-undefined

In addition check the grid troubleshooting: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/troubleshooting